# Returning a buffer from c function

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    
dosome();

}


char* dosome() {
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);    
    
    gets(buffer);

    puts(buffer);

    return buffer;
}
```

I want to return the buffer, so it can be printed, or worked with in the main function in some way. This gives a reutrn type error though
I'm aware that gets() is not safe. This is a proof of concept

The error looks as follows
simple.c:11:7: error: conflicting types for ‘dosome’
11 | char* dosome() {
|       ^~~~~~

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: You need to declare a function before using it. So move `dosome` definition up before `main` or declare a prototype.

Comment: Never use `gets`.

Answer (score -3):

You didn't declare the function

Add `char * dosome();` Somewhere near the main function

Comment: You don't "initialize" a function.

Comment: *You didn't initialize the function* - you mean "declared". Also "near" can be after as well.

Comment: And what do you mean by the "empty buffer" reference? Why should `gets` need a buffer with anything in it?

Comment: @kaylum He declared buffer in dosome(), and then used gets() on it as if there was a value in it already

Comment: What? `gets` writes to the buffer. It doesn't care what is in the buffer to start with.

Comment: @kaylum You're wrong and i'm right okay. In other words, i'll remove it from my post